# Как правильно получить данные с сервера в initial state React Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux-thunk

При отрисовки приложения нужно получать данные с сервера и отрисовывать их. Не могу понять почему у меня state пустой.

app.js

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import AddNoteButton from './components/add-note-button/add-note-button';
import AddNote from './components/add-note/add-note';
import NotesList from './components/notes-list/notes-list';
import TagsList from './components/tags-ist/tags-list';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const App = () => {
  const state = useSelector((state) => state);
  console.log(state);

    const [ showAddNote, setShowAddNote ] = useState(false);
    const [ tags, setTags ] = useState([]);

    // Get all tags
    const getAllTags = (notes) => {
        const newTags = new Set();
        notes.map((note) => {
            return note.tags.forEach((it) => newTags.add(it));
        });

        return [ ...newTags ];
    };

    //Sort notes
    const sortNotes = (checked, value) => {
        setTags(!tags.includes(value) && checked ? [ ...tags, value ] : tags.filter((n) => n !== value));
    };

    const filteredNotes = state.filter((note) => {
        return !tags.length || tags.find((item) => note.tags.includes(item));
    });

    return (
        <div className="wrapper has-background-dark">
            <div className="container is-fluid">
                <div className="columns has-text-light">
                    <div className="wrapper-column column has-background-dark">
                        <AddNoteButton onAdd={() => setShowAddNote(!showAddNote)} isDisabled={showAddNote} />
                        <TagsList tags={getAllTags(state)} onSort={sortNotes} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="wrapper-column column has-background-dark is-three-quarters">
                        {showAddNote ? <AddNote onHide={() => setShowAddNote(false)} /> : ''}
                        <NotesList notes={filteredNotes} />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```

index.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { store } from './state/store';
import { fetchNotes } from './state/action-creators';

store.dispatch(fetchNotes());

ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <Provider store={store}>
            <App />
        </Provider>
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))

reportWebVitals();
```

store.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import reducers from './reducers/index';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

export const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(thunk));
```

reducers

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import notesReducer from './notesReducer';

const reducers = combineReducers({
notes: notesReducer
});

export default reducers;
```

reducer

```
let initialState = [];

   const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
    case 'loadNotes':
        return [ ...state, action.payload ];
    default:
        return state;
}
};

export default reducer;
```

action creator

```
export const fetchNotes = () => {
return async (dispatch) => {
    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/notes');
const json = await res.json();
dispatch(loadNotes(json));
console.log(json);
};
};

export const loadNotes = (notes) => ({
type: 'loadNotes',
payload: notes
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`store.dispatch(fetchNotes());` нужно убрать из `index.js`

В `app.js` добавить

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();

useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(fetchNotes());
}, []);
```

`useDispatch` нужно импортировать из `react-redux`

```
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
```

Хук `useEffect` отработает один раз при монтировании компонента и загрузит данные с сервера.

Comment: А как мне потом получить state правильный? Он всё равно пустой. Или мне стейт нужно получать тоже в хуке? Но тогда как я к нему получу доступ для функций которые вызываются вне хука?

Comment: Ну то есть после этого 
 const dispatch = useDispatch();

 useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(fetchNotes());

 }, []);

  const state = useSelector((state) => state);
  console.log(state);

state всё  равно пусто

Comment: `console.log(state)` прямо в теле функции срабатывает, когда данных еще нет. Попробуйте так: `useEffect(() => { console.log(state); }, [state]);`

Comment: Честно говоря не понимаю почему не работает. Сейчас state мне возвращает [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]. И соответственно в дальнейшем функции падают. Вообще не могу понять где ошибка.